# Bashrc not loaded when running Gradle script from Android Studio

Tags: android, bash, gradle

I have a problem with Gradle script on Ubuntu 16.04. It looks like my .bashrc is not loaded when I'm invoking script from Android Studio.

My script:

```
task myTask {
doLast {
    exec {
        workingDir project.rootProject.rootDir
        commandLine 'll' // alias provided from my .bashrc
    }
}
```

When I'm starting it with `./gradlew myTask` everything works, but when starting from gui I'm getting

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'll''

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run `source` manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir project.rootProject.rootDir
            commandLine 'bash', '-c', '-i', 'll' // alias provided from my .bashrc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. What about other platforms? Do I need to have separate command for Mac and Windows?

Comment: This is just an example. Is it possible to set interactive bash as default for Gradle?

Comment: You can write your own exec task wrapping this behavior